# How to improve real time search with a QSortFilterProxyModel filter in a TreeView?

Tags: c++, qt

I've implemented a search filter to search for data in a `TreeView/QAbstractItemModel` with `QSortFilterProxyModel`. I'm using `QLineEdit` to search the entire tree for data. Every time the text in `QLineEdit` changes, the function to search the tree (real-time search) is called.

My `TreeView` has the ability to grow, so I could have a `tree` with few elements, an the search works very well and it does it quite fast. The problem is when I have a tree with many nodes, and each node has children that can also contain children. When this happens, the search is slow, there is a delay when I type something on my keyboard and when the text appears in the search bar. The same thing happens when I delete all the text I typed in the search bar. It is something similar to when a program is going to freeze or crash.

For example, if I want to search for "hello world", there is a delay when I start to type the first letter "h" or "H", I think this happens because there are many letters "h/H" in my `TreeModel`.

Maybe I forgot to include something, and it makes the search slow. This is the code I'm using:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    TreeModel *model = new TreeModel(file.readAll());
    file.close();

    lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &MainWindow::searchItem);

    proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(0); 
    proxyModel->setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    proxyModel->setDynamicSortFilter(true);
    proxyModel->setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(true); //Search on childs
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model); 

    treeView = new QTreeView(this);
    treeView->setModel(proxyModel);
    treeView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    treeView->expandAll();
}

void MainWindow::searchItem() {
    //proxyModel->setFilterRegularExpression(searchFilter->text());
    proxyModel->setFilterFixedString(searchFilter->text());
}
```

I test with `setFilterFixedString` and `setFilterRegularExpression` and the result is the same.

If I replace my `signal/slow` connection with `connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, &MainWindow::searchItem);` the search function will call only when the `return key` is pressed, it works better and the issue I mention above disappears, but I really want to keep the real time search.